# Trying to update table in asp.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Saving the change to a temp variable is successful as when debugging I can see the values changing, however when I actually try to save the changes to the database, the required field is not being changed.

I am trying to change the value of the field from 'Being Investigated' to 'Closed'

```
nemesysEntities db2 = new nemesysEntities();
report report = db2.reports.Find(investigation.report_id);
report_status rep = db2.report_status.Find(3);
report.report_status = rep;
report.report_status.description = "Closed";
report.report_status.id = 3;
db2.Entry(report).State= EntityState.Modified;
db2.SaveChanges();
```

The table that stores the reports is called reports, and investigation.report_id represents the id of the report being investigated. Hence by passing the report id as a value, the table should find the report in the reports table and change the value of the action status to Closed, by the below line of code, (the id of the action "closed" in the database is 3)

```
report_status rep = db2.report_status.Find(3);
```

However the required changes in the database are not being stored.
Any ideas??

This is the model of the report

---

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Web;

public partial class report
{

    public report()
    {

        this.investigations = new HashSet<investigation>();
        HttpCookie _userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["User"];
        string userId="";
        nemesysEntities db = new nemesysEntities();
        if(_userId!=null)
        {
            this.user_id = Convert.ToInt32(_userId["Id"]);
            user temp=db.users.Find(user_id);
            this.email = temp.email;
            this.phone = temp.phone;
            temp.ConfirmPassword = temp.password;
            int i = temp.points;
            i++;
            temp.points = i;
            db.Entry(temp).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.user_id = 13;
        }
        this.status_id = 1;
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date of near miss")]
    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Location")]
    public string location { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Type")]
    public int type_id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int status_id { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public int votes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<investigation> investigations { get; set; }
    public virtual report_status report_status { get; set; }
    public virtual report_type report_type { get; set; }
    public virtual user user { get; set; }
}
}
```

This is the model of the investigator. You can see that in one of the setters I am using the same method I am attempting to use to change the status of the report.

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Web;

public partial class investigation
{

    public investigation()
    {
        HttpCookie _userId = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["User"];
        if (_userId != null)
        {
            this.investigator_id = Convert.ToInt32(_userId["Id"]);
            //5 is the primary key of "Being investigated" in type of action
            this.action_id = 5;
            this.cause = "";
            this.date_of_action = new DateTime(2012, 1, 3);

        }
    }
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display (Name="Formal Description")]
    public string formal_description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Cause of Hazard")]
    public string cause { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Action Take")]
    public int action_id { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Date of Action")]
    public System.DateTime date_of_action { get; set; }
    public int investigator_id { get; set; }
    int _report_id;
    [Display(Name = "Report Id:")]
    public int report_id
    {
        get
        {
            return _report_id;
        }
        set
        {

            _report_id = value;
            nemesysEntities db = new nemesysEntities();
            report report = db.reports.Find(this.report_id);
            //2 is the primary key of "Being investigated" in report status
            report_status rep = db.report_status.Find(2);
            report.report_status = rep;
            db.Entry(report).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual investigation_action investigation_action { get; set; }
    public virtual report report { get; set; }
    public virtual user user { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Use a sql profiler to look at the sql statement that is generated. And also I am not sure why are you doing report.report_status.id = 3??

Comment: That line and the previous do not really make sense, was just trying anything that came in mind. I will look into using an sql profiler though I presently have no idea what it means and what it does. The funny thing is that in the model, I am using the same method to set the action (in the setter) the first time to 'Being Investigated' and it works fine.

Comment: SQL profiler will lock all the sql statement that is running against your databse, so you can take a look at raw sql. Okay If I understand you corrently, you have a report object and it has relationship with a table called report_status. is that right? If my assumption are corrent then your model should look like report.reportstatus or something similar. Currently I can see that you are updating reporting status table not report

Comment: I think you understood quite well though in the below line of code am I not passing the actual report table, so that is where it is supposed to save, right?

    db2.Entry(report).State= EntityState.Modified;
    db2.SaveChanges();

Comment: yes, but you are not setting the id of status for REPORT, you are updating report status object. Can you paste your report model here? it will make things clear for me

Comment: I edited the question with the report model code

Comment: What I can see from here, you are retrieving report status as an individual object not as part of report object. So when you set report state to modified its not tracking the changes. I suggest you set rep to modified (not report) and submit changes. It should work